# How to set the root path of static website

Tags: html, root, radix

Say my local website folder is at /home/me/website. I want tag refs such as "/images" to point to /home/me/website/images but when hosted online I want https://example.com/images.

I tried using a base tag on each page but with or without a base tag locally "/images" is looking for it in the root of my computer (I think). Base tag only seems to work with relative links like "images".

So I'm asking how to define the root of my website locally so that "/" points to my websites folder (so I can debug) but no change when hosted online.

Thanks.

Comment: When you host it online, put your code in `/var/www/html/` directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use **./images** or **../website/images**